# Is it possible to set a unique position for fetched [ fetch() method ] items rendered as an <a-entity>? | A-Frame Question

Tags: javascript, three.js, fetch, aframe

I can move my fetched assets around in the aframe inspector, but I can't save them in different positions. When I refresh the page, they go back to the original position.

[Link to Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO2YI.png)

The picture in the link shows the box elements I created from the fetched endpoints. They are all rendered in one place. How you see them now is the result of me moving them in the aframe inspector.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>A-Frame</title>
       <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame" />
       <!-- Scripts -->
       <script src="component/render.js"></script>
       <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
       <script>
  
        AFRAME.registerComponent("load", {
          init: function() {
            const box = document.querySelector("#box");
            const sceneEl = document.querySelector("#app");
            const box1 = document.createElement("a-entity");
              box1.nodeValue = getFacts(box1);
          }
        });
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>

     <a-scene id="app" load background="color: #FAFAFA">
        <a-entity position="4.461 0.442 5.224" rotation="0 90 0">
           <a-camera position="0 0 0" active="true" />
        </a-entity>
     </a-scene>
   </body>
```

I've tried giving them their own IDs in my  but that didn't work.
I've also tried saving the positions to its unique ID with the aframe-watcher, no dice.

```
 function getFacts() {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; indent=4"
      }
    })
     .then(response => {
        return response.json();
     })
     .then(data => {
        console.log(data.data);
        const html = data.data
    .map(user => {
      return `

      <a-entity 
         key="${user.id}" 
         id="${user.id}" 
         geometry="primitive: box"
         material="color: orange; side: double">
      </a-entity>
      `;
    })
    .join("");
    console.log(html);
    const sceneEl = document.querySelector("#app");
    const newcontent = document.createElement("a-entity");
    newcontent.innerHTML = html;
    while (newcontent.firstChild) {
       sceneEl.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log("ERROR"));
```

}

Below is a link to the glitch page with all the code:

[https://glitch.com/~sulky-five-smell](https://glitch.com/%7Esulky-five-smell)

My goal is to be able to move the fetched assets to a position where they will stay and not revert back when the page is refreshed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please also copy the code into the question itself, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-askj

Answer (score 0):

The A-Frame inspector cannot save the changes since browsers don't have access to the files hosted in your local machine or server. You can use the inspector to copy the HTML back to your code ([see button on top right corner of the components panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFS1d.png)) or setup a local development workflow using the [aframe-watcher](https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-watcher)